# stuck in responsive menu for days

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am a beginner in html and have been working on a responsive website
I have tried multiple of solutions
but it just doesn't work the way I want
so I have this row which is 1 by 6 to be put in the middle of the homepage
I want it to be resized to 3 by 2 automatically when the window resizes
and 2 by 3 if further resizes
however, the one I have now only resize to a smaller 1 by 6
the column doesn't move to the next line
please help me out here

```css
.frontpage_graphical_container {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 1000px;
}

.frontpage_graphical_row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.frontpage_graphical_col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.frontpage_graphical_option {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.option_name {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(102, 206, 213);
}
```

```html
<div class="frontpage_graphical_container" style="background-color:rgb(151, 237, 224)">
  <div class="frontpage_graphical_row" style="background-color:rgb(45, 98, 97)">
    <div class="frontpage_graphical_col" style="background-color:rgb(115, 172, 225)">
      <span class="frontpage_graphical_option" style="background-color:rgb(215, 114, 231)">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-sack-dollar" style="font-size:50px; color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
                    </span>
      <div class="option_name">
        <i>私人貸款</i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="frontpage_graphical_col" style="background-color:rgb(114, 153, 231)">
      <span class="frontpage_graphical_option" style="background-color:rgb(120, 231, 114)">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-credit-card" style="font-size:50px; color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
                    </span>
      <span class="option_name">
                        <i>信用卡</i>
                    </span>
    </div>

    <div class="frontpage_graphical_col" style="background-color:rgb(231, 186, 114)">
      <div class="frontpage_graphical_option" style="background-color:rgb(231, 114, 208)">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-route" style="font-size:50px; color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="option_name">
        <i>旅遊保險</i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="frontpage_graphical_col" style="background-color:rgb(231, 114, 208)">
      <div class="frontpage_graphical_option" style="background-color:rgb(202, 231, 114)">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-building-columns" style="font-size:50px; color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="option_name">
        <i>虛擬銀行</i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="frontpage_graphical_col" style="background-color:rgb(136, 231, 114)">
      <div class="frontpage_graphical_option" style="background-color:rgb(114, 147, 231)">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-arrow-trend-up" style="font-size:50px; color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="option_name">
        <i>證券戶口</i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="frontpage_graphical_col" style="background-color:rgb(102, 206, 213)">
      <div class="frontpage_graphical_option" style="background-color:rgb(102, 206, 213)">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star" style="font-size:50px; color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="option_name">
        <i>理財戶口</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to class `.frontpage_graphical_row` and the elements will move to the next line automatically when there's not enough space.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply but only 2 columns get move down to the next line?
how can I make it to a 3 by 2 menu

Comment: than you need to specify at how many pixels the new settings should occur and work with media queries.

Comment: You could also consider using `display: grid` and then use media queries to set the columns you wish at that specific screen-size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it would be easier to do using `grid` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead `flex`, but I made one example with each method:

```css
/* For Grid Method */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 10px; /* Only if you wanna separate the items */
}

.grid__col { /* This centers the content inside every column */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { /* Media query for tablets */
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) { /* Media query for desktop */
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  }
}

/* For Flex Method */

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* It makes move items to the next line where overflows */
  margin: -5px; /* Only if you wanna separate the items, half the value of .grid class attribute */
}

.flex__col,
.flex__col:after,
.flex__col:before {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Only if you wanna separate the items, same number of px than .flex class margin */
}

.flex__col {
  width: calc(100% / 2); /* Divide the horizontal space between two elements (columns) */
  padding: 5px; /* Only if you wanna separate the items, same number of px than .flex class margin */
}

.flex__col-inner { /* This centers the content inside every column */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    height: 100%; /* Optional, to make all elements have the same height */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex__col {
    width: calc(100% / 3); /* Divide the horizontal space between three elements (columns) */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .flex__col {
    width: calc(100% / 6); /* Divide the horizontal space between six elements (columns) */
  }
}


/* Test only purpouses */ 

.grid__col,
.flex__col-inner {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Method</h1>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__col">
    <div class="grid__col-inner">Grid 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    <div class="grid__col-inner">Grid 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    <div class="grid__col-inner">Grid 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    <div class="grid__col-inner">Grid 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    <div class="grid__col-inner">Grid 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">
    <div class="grid__col-inner">Grid 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Flex Method</h1>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex__col">
    <div class="flex__col-inner">Flex 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
    <div class="flex__col-inner">Flex 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
    <div class="flex__col-inner">Flex 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
    <div class="flex__col-inner">Flex 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
    <div class="flex__col-inner">Flex 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
    <div class="flex__col-inner">Flex 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But for the grip the column I created always ends up on the top left corner it doesnlt stay in the middle

Comment: Because you need another div inside every column to align the content. I updated my answer to show you how to do that.